Specifying a toplevel installation directory
I am building the lean prover system
git clone https://github.com/leanprover/lean4 --recurse-submodules
cd lean4
mkdir -p build/release
cd build/release
cmake ../..
make

But rather than using a standard install I want to specify the toplevel installation directory.  What can I do ?

I hope Marcus Muller's answer will work for you, but in my experience, things are never that easy. I find it's usually easier to just let the package install to the default location, or put it in a container.
If your worried about polluting your system (valid concern), consider packaging it.  That would be distro-specific, so we'd need to know your distro... but you'd end up using rpm/SPEC, PKGBUILD, or debian/{control,rules} to make a package that can be installed with yum pacman or apt/dpkg and can be uninstalled/upgraded without hassle.
If you really want to install it to an arbitrary path (example: /opt/lean4/), then consider these cmake arguments:
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/lean4

This will make cmake's intall() commands target a directory relative to CMAKE_ISNTALL_PREFIX.  You may get a tree structure like this for example:
/opt/lean4/bin/lean
/opt/lean4/lib/liblean.so
/opt/lean4/etc/lean.cfg

But the problem is that lean doesn't link to ../lib/liblean.so, so you'll need to ensure you also have:
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH="$ORIGIN/../lib"

So make sure that the RPATH points to the path from your executable to your libraries.
Next, you'll need to check any config (/etc/) or resources (/usr/share) files.  Often we add include(GNUInstallDirs) to make life easy. But if you're resisting the default locations, this can make things hard.   Check out this link for where your stuff might end up.
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html
Of course, if your /etc/lean4.cfg ends up in /etc/opt/... you'll need to somehow tell your program the path of the new file and that might require command line parameters, environment variables, or something else.  Things aren't usually programmed to search relative to the binary.
So in summary, I do recommend packaging, containerizing, or accepting defaults over this effort (which I did way too many times before I realized I didn't get any value out of it).

specify -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX when you call cmake, i.e., replace
cmake ../..

with
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/where/I/want/things/to/be/installed ../..

